# Symfony Doctrine skeleton files

Tags: symfony1, doctrine

I'm using Symfony 1.4 with the Doctrine 1.2 plugin.

I would like to add some function to the Doctrine auto-generated models files (*Base.class.php).
Thoses file are normally generated using "./symfony doctrine:build-model" command from the CLI. I know Symfony have a system of skeleton for every file generated from the CLI but I habe absolutely no idea how to modify specific Doctrine skeletons files.

I've looked a the documentation but didn't find any hints. Is this even possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Searching for 'auto-generated by' in symfony, I found this file : lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/Import/Builder.php , which does not seem to use any skeleton system at all... condolences...

Comment: wow. No template system at all. The generation is hardcoded everywhere. I'm starting the hate Doctrine more and more everyday.

Comment: Eh, as I'm hating symfony and all its components more every day! This is an everlasting battle against Potencier's wonderful ideas! It seems that this guy takes his ideas from an unicorn's ass.

Comment: O_o well, I find Doctrine and Symfony very good actually... what's wrong them? I mean... I don't know any better framework / ORM in php out there... but perhaps too unexperienced.