# NetBeans autocompletion with Doctrine models?

Tags: netbeans, symfony1, doctrine, phpdoc, doctrine-1.2

I know it's possible to get IDE autocompletion from the *Table classes in Doctrine by doing things like this:

```
SomethingTable::getInstance()-><autocomplete>;
```

But the most important part is missing.  I want autocomplete on the model classes themselves, not just the *Table classes.  It appears that Doctrine is not properly declaring the PHPdoc @return object types in the find* and other standard model methods.

For example what I want to be able to do is this:

```
$something = SomethingTable::getInstance()->find($id);
$something-><autocomplete>
```

and have that pop up the methods and properties of the Something class.

I should mention too that I don't specifically care about using the SomethingTable::getInstance() syntax at all.  ANY decent syntax that's standard Symfony is acceptable.  Most of the time I'm fetching objects (or Doctrine_Collections) via custom queries like this:

```
$somethings = Doctrine_Query::create()
                ->from('Something s')
                ->leftJoin('s.SomethingElse s2')
                ->where(...);
```

By the way, in case it's not clear, I'm asking if there's any automatic solution to this with ANY of the various Doctrine find, fetch or query syntaxes. I'm NOT asking how to manually edit all the PHPdoc headers to cause the behavior I want.

I'm using NetBeans 6.9.1 and Symfony 1.4.12 with Doctrine, but not everyone working on the same code uses NetBeans.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that autogenerated *Table classes have the wrong phpdoc @return in the getInstance() method:

```
/**
 * Returns an instance of this class.
 *
 * @return object MyModelTable
 */
 public static function getInstance()
 {
     return Doctrine_Core::getTable('MyModel');
 }
```

You just need to manually fix the @return line deleting the word "object":

```
 * @return MyModelTable
```

And magically IDE autocompletion just works, giving you all the instance and static methods:

```
MyModelable::getInstance()->... //(you'll have autocompletion here)
```

I know, its a pain to have to manually fix this but at least it only have to be done once for each model *Table file.

Answer (score 1):

In netbeans its quite easy:

```
$foo = ModelNameTable::getInstance()->find(1); /* @var $foo ModelName */
```

`/* @var $foo ModelName */` tells netbeans to handle the variable $foo as a ModelName class.

Comment: While this is a potentially useful kludge, it suffers drastically from being necessary to do practically everywhere.  I'm looking for a solution that either fixes this for the most common Doctrine situations WITHOUT requiring a bunch of edits like this.

Comment: There's too much magic in Doctrine for that could be so easy.

Answer (score 0):

just fix the generated model files by adding

```
/**
 * @return ModelNameTable
 */
```

in the comment of the getInstance() method. This will provide autocomplete for the model file.
Regarding the find method, you can edit the comment of the **class** like this :

```
/**
 * @method ModelName find()
 */
```

<strike>I think it might be possible for you to do this automatically by creating you own skeleton files.</strike>
Or not : [Symfony Doctrine skeleton files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4000351/symfony-doctrine-skeleton-files)

You could use sed to achieve this, or perhaps build your own task using the reflection api.